# Is there a tradition to pronounce kamatz katan as "a"?

Tags: pronunciation, mesorah-tradition, vowels-nekudot

There are many ways of pronouncing Hebrew in prayers and when reading the *Tora*. Most of these are tradition-based: one pronounces it the same way his parent or teacher did, or a close approximation. Over the years, of course, the amount of error in those approximations amounts to quite a bit, which presumably explains the wide divergence of pronunciation.

*Ashk'nazim* typically pronounce a [*kamatz*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamatz) as a fairly [back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_vowel), not very [open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_vowel) vowel: something like [ʌ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) or [ɔ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel).

*S'faradim*, on the other hand, typically pronounce

- a [*kamatz katan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamatz) as a fairly [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_vowel), back, [round](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_vowel) vowel, something like [o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel); and
- a [*kamatz gadol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamatz) as a fairly open, [central](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_vowel), [unrounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrounded_vowel) vowel, something like [a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel).

Now, I've heard some people pronounce even a [*kamatz katan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamatz) as a fairly open, central, unrounded vowel, something like [a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel). (Or many a *kamatz katan*, anyway.) I've always assumed this is not based on the tradition they received from a line of teachers and ancestors: am I right, or is there some tradition that pronounces the vowel this way?

Comment: I think it's just an effect of Modern Israeli Hebrew.

Comment: It could also be an effect of non-fluent speakers combined with texts (e.g. siddurim) that don't distinguish via typography.  I've seen lots of people who don't know the difference between "kol" and "kal" because they look the same and they don't know the grammar rules.  Some siddurim published in the last couple decades have started distinguishing them; whether that's the reason I don't know, but it seems to help.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ditto. Just think about the words with aקמץ קטן that everyone seems to pronounce "something like o," e.g. קרבן and כל.

Comment: @Fred, I think _Ashk'nazim_ outside of Israel without an Israel- or _S'faradi_-influenced education pronounce "קרבן" and "כל" with the same _kamatz_ as every other word with a _kamatz_.

Comment: @msh210 Are you saying they don't distinguish between different kinds of kamatz?

Comment: @Fred, yes (as indicated in the question).

Comment: @msh210 That's simply not my experience, except for when they unknowingly err (which is frequently for some people). I don't think I've ever heard anyone of any nationality intentionally pronounce קרבן and כל with an "a sound", unless they were unfamiliar with those words to begin with.

Comment: @Fred, I've never heard anyone say "קרבן" or "כל" with an 'a' sound either. As I said in my previous comment, I've heard _Ashk'nazim_ outside of Israel without an Israel- or _S'faradi_-influenced education pronounce them with the same _kamatz_ they use in every other word with a _kamatz_, which (as indicated in the question) is not an 'a' sound.

Comment: when you say tradition...

Comment: You could improve your question by actually linking to an audio file where these are pronounced the way you mean.

Comment: @barlop, the "o" and "a" links in the question are to pages that incorporate such files.

Comment: @msh210 you included 3 or 4 links for o and 3 or 4 links for a, I don't know which one of those links has an audio file and where. And you described one of the links as being something like o and something like a, so if that link has any audio files they wouldn't be what you mean. Can you link to a file that is exactly what you mean?

Comment: @msh210 If they are pronouncing a Kamatz Katan like a Kamatz Gadol, then how do you even know they are doing a Kamatz Katan? They may be doing a Kamatz Gadol.  The rules for when it's a Kamatz Katan and when it's a Kamatz Gadol are not always that well taught, and it is very common in laining or davening to get it wrong on some words. Good examples are in Kiddush. Correct is "VeShoMuhRu" (kamatz katan and vocal shva) but many people say VeShamru which is wrong.   A word like Kol is a very common word and they know by ear. But many a kamatz katan slips.

Comment: And mainstream siddurim often or usually don't mark them. In time if that changes or the more that changes, the more people will know and get it right.  (or as right as the siddur, to the extent that the siddur is right!) And the less you'll see kamatz katan missed. Same with Chumashim.

Comment: Actually, most Ashkenazim pronounce kamatz katan like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_rounded_vowel or like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_rounded_vowel

Answer (score 3):

All Sephardic/Mizrahi (but not Yemenite) reading traditions distinguish qames qatan (pronounced as you point out approximately "o") from qames gadhol (pronounced as you point out approximately "a").  Most Ashkenazim, along with Yemenites, pronounce both approximately as "aw" in claw, draw.  Some Ashkenazim pronounce qames gadhol as "aw" and qames qatan as "o".
Great confusion has resulted when people from an Ashkenazic background make a partial switch to Modern Hebrew pronunciation.  They often don't know to distinguish qames qatan from qames gadhol, and even if they do don't know which is which.
One should note that the rules of qames qatan in Modern Hebrew differ from the Sephardic reading tradition as follows:  a qames preceding hateph-qames is qames-qatan according to Modern Hebrew (e.g., tsohorayim), but is qames gadhol according to Sephardic reading tradition (tsahorayim).
It would be a reasonable assumption that where the last-mentioned rule does not apply, someone pronounced qames-qatan as "a" is simply making an error. 
There are, of course, many situations where authorities dispute over a particular qames followed by a shewa as to whether it is qames-qatan followed by shewa nah or qames-gadhol followed by shewa-na`.

Comment: I have never understood what this 'aw' as in draw means. You distinguish it from 'o'. Do you mean the 'aw' as in bus?   You write "Most Ashkenazim, along with Yemenites, pronounce both approximately as 'aw' in claw, draw. "  The British pronounce Draw/Bore/Snore, the same. And a Kamatz Gadol like Bus.

Comment: it looks like 'aw' is the way the concise oxford english dictionary (COD) did 'o'. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English   Then in the 8th edition 1990, they adopted IPA.  The Linguistics Student's Handbook - Page 127  "....the International Phonetic Alphabet was adopted for use in .....the eighth edition of The Concise Oxford Dictionary (1990)...."

Comment: When you say "Most Ashkenazim, along with Yemenites, pronounce both approximately as "aw" in claw, draw"  You have to be careful because an american accent is different to an accent elsewhere. And you should specify. You might mean an american aw in claw., not UK, not australian, and perhaps not canadian.  American 'claw' is very different to UK 'claw'

Answer (score -1):

No not really.

Ashkenazi pronunciation of kamatz doesn't exist in american, and is like the British 'o' in 'orange'.  Not 'a'. There aren't two. And it's nothing like 'a'.

Modern Israeli pronunciation has kamatz katan and kamatz gadol.. kamatz gadol is the most common one, it does sound a bit like 'a', but it's still not 'a' it's more like the 'u' in bus. So not like the 'a' in cat.

Sephardi pronunciation of kamatz katan and kamatz gadol is the same as modern israeli.. but the rule of when it is kamatz katan and when it is kamatz gadol is a bit simpler.

Patach in sephardi and modern israeli are same as kamatz gadol.

I have heard that syrians pronounce patach like the 'a' in cat.

There may be a persian pronunciation of kamatz that is worth looking into. But it wouldn't be like the 'a' in cat.