# Ashkenazi Pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

There is a different thread that said the Ashkenazi pronunciation does not have an “oh” sound for the kamatz katan. Is that correct? I suppose it would make sense given the difference in how they pronounce the kamatz and patach. That said, if that is true, how do they pronounce words like קָרְבַּן and קָדְשֶׁךָ? Would they be kaw-r-ban rather than korban and kaw-d-shecha?

Comment: Some people may be uneducated on the kamatz katan, but it is certainly pronounced by many Ashkenazim just as you say: “oh”.

Comment: @ezra that doesn't make it classically an ashkenazi phenomenon. Most people don't pronounce Hebrew like their great grandfathers did.

Comment: @DoubleAA it’s not exclusively an ashkenazi issue tho

Comment: @ezra what isn't?

Comment: I have never heard a difference in quality and quantity between kamatz katan and gadol in classical Ashkenazi pronunciation, both are pronounced as "o" (IPA: ɔ) or "u" (IPA: u). Hence: korban and kodshecho (or kurban and kudshechu).

Comment: You can’t make blanket statements about Hebrew pronunciation because it varies depending on education, locality, and ethnic origin. Some Ashkenazim might pronounce kamatz katan differently and others might not. It seems that many do not.

Comment: I think the premise may be reversed. Kamatz katon is more similar to kamatz gadol in many variants of Ashkenazis, with the phoneme closer approximating the former (see recordings of Benno Weis ז"ל, who was very careful about pronunciation in his work, as he was attempting to accurately pass on Mesauras Frankfurt a/M)

Comment: @ezra You can make blanket statements about established pronunciation schemes that existed back in ashkenazi countries. You're right that nowadays many ashkenazi derived people don't speak a traditional form of ashkenazi Hebrew and have started differentiating two kinds of kamatz, but that doesn't prevent us from identifying traditional forms of ashkenazi Hebrew

Comment: Ashkenazim do distinguish. Koomatz goodoyl is "oo" and koomatz kootun is "uh" ;)

Answer (score 1):

it's more like an "uh." Also, Yemenites have preserved the Kamatz pronunciation. Sephardim haven't.

*** EDIT ***

When I wrote "Sephardim" I meant moreso Israeli "Sephardim" that speak modern Hebrew. Modern Hebrew/pronunciation is great in that it combines everyone into a single unified tongue, but a lot gets lost.

That said, the Mizrachi Sephardim have variances with "Ah," and for a Kamatz ([Is there a tradition to pronounce kamatz katan as "a"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/is-there-a-tradition-to-pronounce-kamatz-katan-as-a)):

1. a kamatz katan as a fairly closed, back, round vowel, something like o; and
2. a kamatz gadol as a fairly open, central, unrounded vowel, something like a (as in black).
3. is interesting because Arabic shares that. Salaam has the "aah" sound at the end as well.

Comment: Rav Ovadia Yosef would like a word with you. As would Moshe Chabusha. Many Sepharadim who are not careful do not distinguish between Patach and Kamatz. But some are careful to distinguish, but the difference is much more subtle compared to Ashkenazim. Rav Ovadia Yosef writes that it is a mistake to think that in the Spharadi pronunciation a “Kamatz” and a “Patach” are identical- there is a subtle difference (Shu”t Yabiya Omer VI Orach Chayyim 11 (4))

Comment: So it is true it is not pronounced “oh” in words like קָרְבַּן? It would be kuh-r-ban rather than korban? There seems to be some contradictory view points in the comments.

Comment: @Asher it's hard to know exactly what you mean by oh aw and uh. English and Hebrew phonemes need not map to each other one-to-one, and English speakers from different regions may pronounce things differently from each other.

Comment: I suppose a more simple question would be do they use the normal sound they use for the Kamatz with these words rather than the “oh” sound of the kamatz katan?

Comment: @Asher The Ashkenazim (at least those ones I met) don't differentiate between the _kamatz gadol_ and _katan._